# Set Customer to Shopping Cart in Magento

Tags: android, magento

I am trying to set existing customer to shopping cart but i am getting "customer's mode is unknown" in fault code from API.Can anyone suggest me what's wrong in this request to set customer, below is the code-

```
    env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    env.dotNet = false;
    env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
    env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;    

    SoapObject customerEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartCustomerEntity");
    customerEntity.addProperty("mode",mode);
    customerEntity.addProperty("customer_id",customerId);
    customerEntity.addProperty("firstname",firstname);
    customerEntity.addProperty("lastname",lastname);
    customerEntity.addProperty("email",email);
    customerEntity.addProperty("website_id",1);

    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartCustomerSet");
    request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
    request.addProperty("quoteId", quoteId);
    request.addProperty("customerData", customerEntity);
    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    (new MarshalHashtable()).register(env);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);

    } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        result = env.getResponse();
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (SoapFault e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

**Replace** 
request.addProperty("*customerData*", customerEntity);
**with**
request.addProperty("*customer*", customerEntity);

Comment: You are right!!But according to the docs the property name is customerData.

Comment: Yeah, but when you check into SOAP client (Firefox plugin) there will be two data set "customerData" and "customer". I tried both, "customer" got worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It may help you.

```
customerEntity.addProperty("mode","customer");
```

And add this field also

```
customerEntity.addProperty("entity_id","yourid");
```

Comment: What is the value of your customer mode your passing?

Comment: customerEntity.addProperty("mode","customer");
  customerEntity.addProperty("customer_id",1744);
  customerEntity.addProperty("firstname","vikas");
  customerEntity.addProperty("lastname","panwar");
  customerEntity.addProperty("email","vikaspanwar.vik9@gmail.com");
  customerEntity.addProperty("website_id",1);
  
  
  request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartCustomerSet");
  request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
  request.addProperty("quoteId",8704);
  request.addProperty("customerData", customerEntity);

Comment: plz check with replace the "customer_id" field to "entity_id"

Comment: I am getting SoapFault - faultcode: '1045' faultstring: 'Customer's mode is unknown' faultactor: 'null' detail: null this in the response after changing customer_id to entity_id.

Comment: Check your magento admin panel you created a role for customer, if not create one and try. Or else try to pass the role which created in admin panel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65809/discussion-between-vikas-panwar-and-remees-m-syde).

Answer (score 0):

```
`<complexType name="shoppingCartCustomerEntity">
<all>
<element name="mode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="customer_id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="email" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="firstname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="lastname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="password" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="confirmation" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="website_id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="store_id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="group_id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
</all>
</complexType>`
```

Here's the wsdl scheme of the shopping cart customer entity.
To check the passing parameters for further requests:put 'http://yourdomainname//api/v2_soap/?wsdl' in your web browser.